# Errors c2660 and c2061 C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having problems handling the following errors:

> c2660: c:\users\lukas plaehn\desktop\oop\sokoban\sokoban\main.cpp(126): error C2660: 'CPlayer::moveUp' : function does not take 1 arguments
>
> c2061: c:\users\lukas plaehn\desktop\oop\sokoban\sokoban\player.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CMaze'

What I am trying to do is pass an object as a parameter in a header file. I have tried doing it by reference too but its not working. Somehow the compiler is not allowing my declaration of anything of type `CMaze` in the header file `CPlayer`.

```
    class CPlayer:public CBlocks
    {
    public:
    CMaze * m;
    CPlayer(void);
    CPlayer(char sym, int x, int y, CMaze mz);
    ~CPlayer(void);
    void moveUp(CMaze maze);
    void moveDown(CMaze maze);
    void moveLeft(CMaze maze);
    void moveRight(CMaze maze);
};

    #include "Player.h"
    #include "Maze.h"
    //#include "headers.h"




    CPlayer::CPlayer(void)
    {
    }

    CPlayer::CPlayer(char sym, int x, int y, CMaze mz)
    {
    m = &mz;
    m_symbol = sym;
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    }

    CPlayer::~CPlayer(void)
    {
    }



    void CPlayer::moveDown(CMaze maze)
    {
    if(m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol == ' ')
    {
        m->arr[m_y+1][m_x] = m->arr[m_y][m_x];
        m->arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
    }
    else if(m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol == '#')
    {
        cout << "You cannot perform this move!"<<endl;
    }
    else if(m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol == '$')
    {
        if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            m->arr[m_y+2][m_x] = m->arr[m_y+1][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y+1][m_x] = m->arr[m_y][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            m->arr[m_y+2][m_x] = m->arr[m_y+1][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol = '*';
            m->arr[m_y+1][m_x] = m->arr[m_y][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   

    }

    else if(m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol == '.')
    {
        m->arr[m_y+1][m_x] = m->arr[m_y][m_x];
        m->arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol = '+';
    }
    else if(m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol == '*')
    {
        if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            m->arr[m_y+2][m_x] = m->arr[m_y+1][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol = '$';
            m->arr[m_y+1][m_x] = m->arr[m_y][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol = '+';
            m->arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            m->arr[m_y+2][m_x] = m->arr[m_y+1][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y+1][m_x] = m->arr[m_y][m_x];
            m->arr[m_y+1][m_x].m_symbol = '+';
            m->arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(m->arr[m_y+2][m_x].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   
    }


    }

    void CPlayer::moveUp(CMaze maze)
    {
    if(maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol == ' ')
    {
        maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol == '#')
    {
        cout << "You cannot perform this move!"<<endl;
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol == '$')
    {
        if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol = '*';
            maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   

    }

    else if(maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol == '.')
    {
        maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol = '+';
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol == '*')
    {
        if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol = '$';
            maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol = '+';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y-1][m_x].m_symbol = '+';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y-2][m_x].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   
    }
    }

    void CPlayer::moveLeft(CMaze maze)
    {
    if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol == ' ')
    {
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol == '#')
    {
        cout << "You cannot perform this move!"<<endl;
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol == '$')
    {
        if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol = '*';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   

    }

    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol == '.')
    {
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol = '+';
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol == '*')
    {
        if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol = '$';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol = '+';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x-1].m_symbol = '+';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x-2].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   
    }
    }

    void CPlayer::moveRight(CMaze maze)
    {
    if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol == ' ')
    {
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol == '#')
    {
        cout << "You cannot perform this move!"<<endl;
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol == '$')
    {
        if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol = '*';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   

    }

    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol == '.')
    {
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol = '+';
    }
    else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol == '*')
    {
        if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == ' ')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol = '$';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol = '+';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '.')
        {
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1] = maze.arr[m_y][m_x];
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x+1].m_symbol = '+';
            maze.arr[m_y][m_x] = CSpace(' ', m_x, m_y);
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '$')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '#')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else if(maze.arr[m_y][m_x+2].m_symbol == '*')
        {
            cout << "You cannot perform this move!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unkown Error Occurred" << endl;
        }   
    }
    }


    class CMaze
    {
public:
    friend class CPlayer;

    int m_columns, m_rows;
    string line;
    CBlocks arr[32][48];
    int i, j;
    int k, count;
    bool m_status;


    ifstream mazeStream;


    CMaze(void);
    ~CMaze(void);
    void setStatus(CMaze maze);
    CBlocks fillCharArr();
    void displayMaze();

    };
```

Comment: show us the code.. otherwise there is no way to know.

Comment: Post the code causing the problem, and if this homework tag the question with homework.

Comment: C'mon, take it easy on the new guy...

Comment: @All: At least give OP some time to post the code before downvoting.

Comment: For the record, I did not downvote.

Comment: It would help if you could show us the relevant sections of code. It seems you pass one argument into `moveUp()` while it either takes none or more than one. And perhaps you're using `CMaze` while in that header file it has no idea what that object is. The more relevant information you can give us though, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: I don't know if this is enough. if not i could add more of the code.
I'm rather new at this so excuse me if the post is not clear and does not contain everything.

EDIT: Oh and the -> in moveDownward() is wrongly made at the moment, because i was trying out different methods of how i could make this work, so i know about that

Comment: I effed with it enough to make it compile. http://ideone.com/3bupX . still need main() code.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaring CMaze and passing by reference will take care of c2061

```
class CMaze;
class CPlayer : public CBlocks
{
    public:
    CMaze * m;
    CPlayer(void);
    CPlayer(char sym, int x, int y, CMaze & mz);
    ~CPlayer(void);
    void moveUp(CMaze & maze);
    void moveDown(CMaze & maze);
    void moveLeft(CMaze & maze);
    void moveRight(CMaze & maze);
}:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that you aren't including the maze header from player.h ... This means that when you pass by value (which is bad as it results in an unnecessary copy) the function doesn't know anything about the CMaze object despite wanting to use it.

I suspect the problem would go away if you passed CMaze as a pointer or a reference.  You do, however, need to bear in mind that by doing this that any subsequent modifications of CMaze inside your function will cause the CMaze passed in to change as well.